# Regarding a math function, which is better?

Tags: mathematics

I I want to have a function depicted graphically, which is better?

- Draw a graphic of the function
- Draw a plot of the function
- Make a graphic of the function
- Make a plot of the function
- Plot a graphic of the function
- Plot the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to say this that are all acceptable.  Each of your example sentences would work, though the noun **graph** is used, rather than graphic.  We also use the verbs "construct" and "sketch" sometimes, as well as the noun "curve" in place of "function."

If I were asking my students to graph points, I would tend to use the word **plot**; it carries the connotation of more carefully placing the points that are drawn.

If instead I were asking my students to draw the general shape of a curve (as in calculus, when you might know the concavity and slope of a curve but not many of the points) then I would probably tell them to **sketch** the curve.

You might also just see the sentence, "Graph f(x)."

So in short: 
Construct/graph/draw/plot a plot/graph/curve of the function/curve.
(Don't "plot a plot" or "graph a graph" though.)